# Incomplete display of README on main page of my package in Pypi?

Tags: python, pypi, readme

I published my personal project on Pypi: [cannondb-pypi](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/cannondb/1.1.1)
here is my github page:[cannondb-github](https://github.com/SimonCqk/cannondb)

README file has converted from markdown to rst, and I do have a exact proper setup.py configuration. But what really confuses me is that the Pypi can not really disply my REAME information.

Comment: At PyPI I see release 1.1.1, at Github only 1.1.0. Have you published the release from not-yet-pushed code? If yes, how we're supposed to guess what's wrong without seeing code?

Comment: `README.rst` in the package at PyPI looks good, `rst2html` converted it to html without a problem.

Comment: I've pushed latest code, and I still can't find anything wrong...